# Converting TextBox number to the integer

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C# and i'm doing this just for practice (this isn't homework)
Okay so I need to convert a text box text (called Numbers) into an integer
I tried something like:

```
int number1;
number1 = int.Parse(Numbers.Text);
```

Then to check if it's right:

```
label1.Text = number1.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(number1.ToString());
```

But integer doesn't hold anything. I get no Message and the label doesn't change.

Additional question: 
Why doesn't the message box doesn't show? 
There were no if statements either switches.

Comment: What is the content of Numbers.Text when you try to parse the string?

Comment: You need to show more code than what you have included at this point.

Comment: Try MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(number1));

Comment: content is custom but only numbers.

Comment: Have you subscribed to an event to trigger the conversion? The event is probably not firing when you expect it to fire.

Comment: I'd imagine there is more you aren't showing us, show us the methods you are using these lines of code in, my guess is its a scope problem

Comment: _"Then to check if it's right...i used the label"_ Use the debugger instead

Comment: I thought the same @TimSchmelter, but ignored that fact as looks like a different lesson is being taught

Comment: So I'm a noob as I said... I fixed the problem by deleting this code double click on the button on the Form1.cs [Design] and then rewriting the code. Problem was it was exactly same each letter and each case but it worked. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Aras - The only thing that could have meant is your event for your button (created when you double click) had disappeared at some point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have verified your code, and what you have posted is fine.

I assume your problem is the code isn't being ran. Make sure the method is being called.
If you can't fix it still, add a new button on the form. Double click on the button, and add that code to the method that is automatically created.
Then test it by clicking on the button at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to user input and parsing, you may want to try [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx). if gives you the ability to parse, but also that secondary feedback letting you know if it was a success or not. For example:

```
Int32 parsed;
String input = "3";
if (Int32.TryParse(input, out parsed)){
  // it was successful and `parsed` = 3
} else {
  // `input` most likely had something invalid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic stuff and should work. Considering that the MessageBox doesn't appear at all, I guess you need to clean your build. Either choose Clean from Solution's context menu, or close the solution and VS, go to project directory, remove bin and obj and come back and rebuild the project.

Comment: I did it but then still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method

```
 int i;
 try
 {
    i=Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
 }
 catch
 {
     //do whatever you want
  }
```